# White space between video div and text div

Tags: html, css, class, video, nav

I have been trying a lot but nothing works, everything I find on the internet doesn't work for me. I have a video that is inside a div called "vidContain", beneath this div is another div for text called "about". Between the "vidContain" div is a unidentified white space, the white space is just 4px small. Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#vidContain">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id='vidContain'>
            <div id='vid'>
                <video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
                    <source src="video/finlay.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
            </video>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="about">
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>

        <div id="services">
            Lorem ipsum
        </div>

        <div id='blog'>
            Lorem Ipsum
        </div>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Brandon Grotesque';
    src: url('BrandonGrotesque-Regular.eot');
    src: url('BrandonGrotesque-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('BrandonGrotesque-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
        url('BrandonGrotesque-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Brandon Grotesque';
    src: url('BrandonGrotesque-Bold.eot');
    src: url('BrandonGrotesque-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('BrandonGrotesque-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
        url('BrandonGrotesque-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}

html, body { 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
}

.nav {  
    z-index:10000;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Lucida Console,Lucida Sans Typewriter,monaco,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,monospace;
    position: fixed;
    text-align:right;
}

.nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.nav ul li {
    display: inline;
}

.nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}


.nav ul li a:hover, .nav ul li .current{
    color: #ffeead;
}

#vidContain {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0px;
}
#vid {
    top: 0; left:0;
    width: 100%; height: auto; 
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
}

h1{
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 6px;
}

h2{
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
    color:grey;
}

#about{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height:500px;
    background-color: #4f444c;
}

#services{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height:500px;
    background-color: white;
}

#blog{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height:500px;
    background-color: #ffeead;
}

video{
    display: block;
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: I guess it is `display:inline-block;` against `#vidContain`, but it is hard to say without actually seeing the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this id `#vidContain` add `property vertical-align: top;` & add this property to  `p` `margin:0;`

Also two time  close video tag

https://jsfiddle.net/wuoaLLsy/

Comment: Adding vertical-align: top; did the job. Thank you very much :).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark without seeing a fiddle or something to see exactly what's going on, but you've got two closing `</video>` tags... Try removing one to see if makes a difference:

```
<div id='vidContain'>
       <div id='vid'>
           <video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
                    <source src="video/finlay.mp4" type="video/mp4">
           </video>
      </div>
 </div>
```